# After "npm link" and "npm i <repo>" cannot resolve module ("main" and "types" are correctly in package.json)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, npm-install

My **package.json** file

```json
{
  "name": "ts-logger",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "install": "tsc"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/vkrenta/ts-logger.git"
  },
   "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^14.6.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
   ...
}
```

My **tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     ...
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "target": "es5",
     ...
    "rootDir": "./"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

I tried to push it to github and run `npm link`.

After I created another npm project, then after `require('ts-logger')` or `import {Logger} from 'ts-logger'` and `node .` I get logs that npm cannot resolve module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in **package.json** - I just swaped `devDependencies` and `dependencies`, because typescript is dependency that compiles code from git to dist folder.

```json
"dependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^14.6.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
```

### UPD

Also I initiated my **tsconfig.json** in package with `"target":"es5"`, but new project with `"target":"es2015"`. So it means that your package target must be newer (or same) than target in your project (the best is `"target":"ESNext"`).